# Listing all buckets in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

Setting up tests for cleaning up local Firebase Emulator environment and need to clear all buckets. For Gcloud implementation [there's a method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets#prereq-code-samples) but can't find equivalent for Firebase Storage. I've tried to cast as `Storage` from `@google-cloud/storage` but that doesn't work. Any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The client-side Firebase SDKs only know about a single bucket, and have now way to list all buckets in a project.

The [server-side Firebase SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) for Cloud Storage are mostly simple wrappers around the GCP SDKs for their platforms, so should give you access to all APIs that those have. If you can't get that to work, edit your question to show what you tried (which would also answer the question of what language you're using).

Comment: Thanks for the push in the right direction, posted an answer, if there's a better alternive way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the push in the right direction, Frank. I'm using server-side Firebase SDKs for NodeJS.

Below did work:

```
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage';

const storageGcp = new Storage();
const [buckets] = await storageGcp.getBuckets();
```

As `getBuckets()` doesn't exist on Firebase's `Storage` object, returned from `getStorage()`, below **didn't** work:

```
import { getStorage } from 'firebase-admin/storage';

const storageFb = new getStorage(); // Also returns Storage
const [buckets] = await storageGcp.getBuckets();
```

Comment: Nice! Good to hear this worked Max! 